# My vehicle fans turn on but no air flows through

Tags: car, repair

I have a 1996 Ford Explorer ~ The interior heat/cool/outside air fans turn on but the air flow from all those vents stopped blowing out air, with the exception of the defroster vents. What could cause this to happen?

Comment: The problem has been solved ~ a vacuum line was knocked off when we installed new spark plugs.